# How to create a ptracable process in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, sudo, process, strace

After Ubuntu Maverik, restrictions were placed on `ptrace` syscall. Now a only the parent process or the sudo user can ptrace a process. We can change this behavior by editing `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` file. But editing that file also requires root access. So is there a way to start a process from shell so that it can be ptracable from **any** other process?